# How does the "webapk7.dex" file get into my assets?

Tags: android, assets, dex, webapk

Examining the structure of my app's assets via AssetManager, I found out that some devices have "webapk7.dex" in the root of the assets. What is this dex file? Which library is responsible for putting it there, or does Android do it?

There are some questions about the webapk technology here on SO, but none of them seems relevant to my project ...

Comment: What IDE or tool do you use for developing your app, Android Studio?

Comment: Yes, Android Studio Arctic Fox